# @OneToMany object is only returning the ID when multiple parents have the same child object

Tags: java, spring-boot, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a many to one relationship present between two of my entities. I am trying to get a JSON object as a response that includes all the details of the child entity when more than one parent has the same child. My problem is that if 2 parent objects both have a child, let's say the child has `ID=5`, the first parent object shows the entire object in the JSON, but the second only shows the ID.

The mapping in the parent entity (PendingTradeSkin.java)

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="skin_details_id")
private SkinDetails skinDetails;
```

The mapping in the child entity (SkinDetails.java)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="skinDetails", cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JsonIgnore
private List<PendingTradeSkin> pendingTradeSkins;
```

The JSON response I am currently getting

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "skinDetails": {
        "id": 5,
        "category": "category",
        "collection": "collection",
        "quality": "quality",
        "wear": "wear",
        "weapon": "weapon",
        "name": "name"
    },
    "price": 0.00,
    "dateBought": "2022-01-19",
    "quantity": 5
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "skinDetails": 5,
    "price": 0.00,
    "dateBought": "2022-01-19",
    "quantity": 5
}
```

What I need is the second object (id=6) to also output the entire `skinDetails` object.

My hunch is that I am doing something incorrect with the @ManyToOne/@OneToMany mapping, but cannot seem to narrow down what is causing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It should not work like this as `skinDetails` is a type of `SkinDetail` . Either it should be a skinDetail object or it should be null how it mapping integer for you. Update your complete model and repository

Comment: @GnanaJeyam I was able to figure out the problem with my model. I included it as an answer below. Thank you for your input on my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer to this issue as it fixed the described problem.

I had the annotation `@JsonIdentityInfo` on my model as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class SkinDetails {
    // class body
}
```

which, according to [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/01/spring-custom-serializers-jsonidentityinfo.html), states that "If the annotation @JsonIdentityInfo is added to the class then any ObjectMapper will break the cycle by replacing every occurrence of the object except the first with its id" which is exactly the issue I was facing in the problem I described.

Removing this annotation from my model fixed my issue and I now get the JSON I was expecting instead of just the ID on the second instance of the same object.

Comment: Thank you so much I was so confused to why it was happening

Comment: You're a hero, thank you. I also couldn't figure out why my mappings were wrong and never would have considered this.